# Importing bitbucket project via GIT to Eclipse failed with errors

Tags: java, php, eclipse, git, bitbucket

Hi  i have installed EGit to my eclipse .

now i am trying to import an existing bitbucket project .

tried steps .

1. in Eclipse - **Window -> prefrerences -> Team -> Git -> Configuration -> Add entry**

[image]

2.**windows -> preferences -> General-> network Coneections -> SSH2 -> Key management - >Generate RSA key** . then saved private key . also added the private key in

**windows -> preferences -> General-> network Coneections -> SSH2 -> General -> Add private Key**

3.in bitbucket

logged in from kanishka@****.com . user name = kanishkapanamaldeniya .

**Manage account -> ssh keys -> Add key.**

4. i have not created any repositories my self , but i have access to a repository .
5. in eclipse **File -> import - > GIT -> projects form git -> Clone Uri** .

[image]

i am getting the following error

[image]

I can not understand why is this happening , please help me , i am stuck here of a long time now , thanks in advance  :)

Comment: Did you setup your SSH keys in BitBucket?

Comment: yes .in bitbucket

logged in from kanishka@****.com . user name = kanishkapanamaldeniya .

Manage account -> ssh keys -> Add key.

Comment: If this is not your repository, then the owner must give you access to it. Maybe this is the problem. Otherwise ... Everything seems to be correct.

Comment: Hi i checked the elipse error log and it says !MESSAGE ssh://git@bitbucket.org/kanishkapanamaldenya/test.git: conq: repository does not exist. but there is a repository called 'test' and also i can access it  , but i did not created it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ssh url would *never* include a user account to access the bitbucket server. It generally use a service account like 'git' (as seen in "[Troubleshoot SSH Issues](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Troubleshoot+SSH+Issues#TroubleshootSSHIssues-SpecificErrorMessages)")

```
git@bitbucket.org:accountname/reponame.git
# or
ssh://git@bitbucket.org/accountname/reponame.git
```

In your case, if you have under your account a test.git repo:

```
ssh://git@bitbucket.org/kanishkapanamaldenya/test.git
```

That means:

- The username for the "authentication" part would be `git`
- The 'password' would be the passphrase associated with your private key (if you created it passphrase-protected) or empty (if your private key isn't passphrase protected)

This presuppose that you have an account `kanishkapanamaldenya` on BitBucket, and that you have a Git repo name `test.git` in BitBucket.
Eclipse itself won't create those two for you. It will simply push to it or pull from it.

A path like "`test/test.git`" wouldn't be a valid BitBucket path anyway.
It is **`accountname/reponame.git`**.
If your account name on BitBucket is `kanishkapanamaldenya`, then the right path would be `kanishkapanamaldenya/test.git`.

Comment: Hi , but then the user will be git , when try to chane my user ,automaticallly the ssh path changes . git becomes kanishkapanamaldeniya , so finally it becomes ssh://kanishkapanamaldenya@bitbucket.org/kanishkapanamaldenya/test.git

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya that is because you are mixing https authentication and ssh. Don't put a username/password.

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya and "`test/test.git`" wouldn't be a valid BitBucket path anyway. It is `accountname/reponame.git`. If your account name on BitBucket is `kanishkapanamaldenya`, then the right path would be `kanishkapanamaldenya/test.git`

Comment: please check my 2 nd screen shot in the question , in that i hae seleced the protocol as SSH , but still it requires user and a password :(

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya then the user would be '`git`', and the 'password' would be the passphrase associated with your private key (if you created it passphrase-protected) or empty (if your private key isn't passphrase protected)

Comment: Hi i checked the elipse error log and it says !MESSAGE ssh://git@bitbucket.org/kanishkapanamaldenya/test.git: conq: repository does not exist. but there is a repository called 'test' and also i can access it  , but i did not created it .

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya of course: all of this presuppose that you have an account `kanishkapanamaldenya` on BitBucket, and that you have a Git repo name `test.git` in BitBucket. Eclipse itself won't create those two for you. It will simply push to it or pull from it.

Comment: managed to import . Thsank you very much for your kind support . all the best :)

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya Great! I have edited the answer to include the comments I have made before, for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

what worked for me was changing the network connection setting from manual to direct.
Window->Preferences->General->Network connections->Active Provider->direct

Answer (score 0):

And, the same error many years later I fixed it by changing git HTTP client:
In eclipse: Window->Preferences->Version Control->Git->HTTP client (I've set it to Java built-in HTTP)

Answer (score 0):

Exact same issue here, just needed to set a new "App Password" in Bitbucket: https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/app-passwords/

That solved it.